# Create a new table while inserting new record

Tags: php, mysql

I have one registration form,in that i want to insert a record into a database but at the same time the new table will be created on clicking submit...but i am facing issue as 'create' query doesnt execute so message appeared as "Something Went Wrong!!! :(".

```
<?php
include('data_conn.php');

if(isset($_POST['subm'])){

  $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['email']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Email is Already Exist...."); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    else {
        $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];

        $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
        $c_add = $_POST['c_add'];
        $mob = $_POST['mob'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];



        $query = "INSERT INTO login (first_name,company_name,company_add,last_name,email,password,account) VALUES ('$f_name','$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password','deactivate')";

       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $query1="CREATE TABLE $db_name.$email('name' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)";


$result1=mysql_query($query1);




       if($result==1 && $result1==1)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("successfully registered!!!"); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';

    }
    else
    {
      echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Something Went Wrong!!! :("); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new table based on the email address? Also, the email address may contain invalid characters for table names.

Comment: boss, you cannot `INSERT` a record, if the table doesn't exist yet. You executed the `INSERT` query, before you create the table.

Comment: the table in  which i want to insert record is different (i.e. login) which is already exist in my db but simultaneously i want to create new table for respective user to add their information...

Comment: so if you have a thousand users do you plan to have a thousand tables? RETHINK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $query1="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $db_name.$email('name' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)"; 
    $result1=mysql_query($query1);
```

Ok  you created some table here. But you are inserting data to a table `login`, why? If the above table is destination, then why this `login` table?
If you created a new table say, `newtable`, use it.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO newtable(first_name,company_name,company_add,last_name,email,password,account) VALUES ('$f_name','$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password','deactivate')";
               $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks ...it works with "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $db_name.$email('name' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)"...thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

// remove ' quotes of table column name

```
$query1="CREATE TABLE $db_name.$email(name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)";
```